# ExtJS: dynamically changing element styles

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to dynamically assign styles to my elements (in this case, a ExtJS `displayfield`).

I can't use CSS classes since I don't know what the colors will be until runtime.

I'm trying:

```
myDisplayField.getEl().applyStyles({ color: '#ff0000' });  //fail
myDisplayField.getEl().setStyle('color', '#ff0000');       //fail
```

Just to get the mechanism right, but neither seem to work.

It works using `Ext.get(<div id>).setStyle(...)`, but that doesn't seem as clean to me. Is there a reason the former attempts don't work?

What am I missing? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is simple: you're trying to set the styles on a wrong element. Each field, including displayfield, has quite complex table-based DOM structure that encapsulates the field label, the actual input element (or a div for display fields), and the supporting elements. `field.getEl()` returns the *top*, or main, element for a component; in this case that's the top `<table>` tag. What you need is the input element instead.

Now if you take a look at the DOM structure you'll notice that the `<div>` that you need to set styles on has an id of `displayfield-123-inputEl`. The -inputEl suffix is there for a reason; in most cases it indicates that the element has a Ext.dom.Element shortcut in its respective Component. For a field, that would be `field.inputEl` property that is available after the field has been rendered to the DOM. You can use that as well:

```
myDisplayField.inputEl.setStyle(...)
```

Or just use the convenience method available for the fields:

```
myDisplayField.setFieldStyle(...)
```

I would also suggest not hardcoding the colors but rather use CSS classes instead. In most cases there is a limited choice of colors depending on a condition, like invalid input, etc. Using CSS will require a bit more work upfront but will save you a lot of headache down the road, when someone will come up with a bright idea of changing the shade of red used for the invalid input, or somesuch.

Comment: To supplement your answer jsfiddle, as I alredy did, and my answer was late) http://jsfiddle.net/eC9j8/

Comment: The colors arn't hardcoded - they just are in this code snippet; in my code they're calculated using a gradient. But I learnt a lot from this answer - greatly appreciate your taking the time to help out

Comment: but why would displayfield and label be so different to each other? displayfield is used in a form context but thats all. So it should be just as easy to modify stylisticly as a label... anyway seems strange to me.